# Laravel - Eloquent Update 1 less than it says?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So I am using Laravel 5.5 and I am having the weirdest issue.
My Database is a MySQL database and whenever I run my query, Debugbar states the correct query however whenever I check the actual database the value is one less than it should.

For example, I gave it the following query (Shown in DebugBar):

```
update `whitelist` set `AdminRank` = '5' where `PlayerUID` = '\"76561198066771722\"'
```

Created using eloquent in the following statement :

```
DB::table('whitelist')
      ->where('PlayerUID', $formData['playerID'])
      ->update(["$colName"=> $rank]);
```

However in the database the 'AdminRank' displays as a value of '4' rather than 5. I have come to a complete loose end here as I have no idea what could be causing this. 
Im tempted to simply add 1 to all my values before updating however I really want to avoid that as it is super hacky.

Side Note : Yes the Player ID is supposed to be in double quotes like that, its a long story but that is not the issue..

Comment: Is `AdminRank` a string or integer in your database?

Comment: It is "ENUM" type. https://gyazo.com/152b488d5d3f2e620686d11e231d7eb2

Comment: So it's something like `$table->enum('AdminRank', ['1','2','3','4','5']);` in your migration?

Comment: My application has to work around an existing table, so no. There is no migration.

Comment: Ok, have you tried using an int instead of a string? ``set `AdminRank` = 5``

Comment: Yes, when i have been testing and forcing data in eg :
https://gyazo.com/555aa7f54cf6249e127f1c30493459d5

it updates to 5.

Comment: I have just confirmed that this only effects ENUM as after creating a test column of int, it works fine. Any workaround you know of or why this could be happening?

Comment: I suspect an indexing issue, MySQL interprets it as an index from an array of values. If the values are defined as `1 => 0,
2 => 1,
3 => 2,
4 => 3,
5 => 4
6 => 5`. That could explain the difference.

Comment: Do you update ENUM by passing it a index?

Comment: Mate that was the solution, hats off to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that laravel interprets ENUMs with a index rather than a value. Thanks to @btl for that one.